# Unable to access system storage in adb shell

Tags: adb

I was trying to install a gsi with DSU sideloader. It needs me to type a command using adb to initialize the installation. But I keep getting this error while running the adb shell command on my pc
adb shell sh/storage
/system/bin/sh: sh/storage: inaccessible or not found

The actual command was adb shell sh/storage/emulated/0/Dsu/workspace_dsuhelper/install
Which also results in the same error: /system/bin/sh: sh/storage/emulated/0/Dsu/workspace_dsuhelper/install : inaccessible or not found.
I know that /storage/emulated/0... exists but I am unable to access it. What could be the issue?

Comment: because `sh/storage/emulated/0/Dsu/workspace_dsuhelper/install` it's not a valid command, you copied it wrong or it's wrong at the source

Answer (score 2):

use this command to get the storage status

adb shell df /data

[image]

Comment: This is not what I asked for but your answer still helped. I missed the space between sh /storage  you added the space after df /data. Thanks anyways. This command worked for me: adb shell sh /storage/emulated/0/Dsu/workspace_dsuhelper/install

Comment: @SahilAhmed why are you invoking sh after shell?